# Import a remote shaded artifact in a Maven project

Tags: maven, cloudera

I am trying to import a shaded artifact in my Maven project from a remote repository, in order to use different library versions, without conflicts.

```
<repository>
  <id>cdh.repo</id>
  <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos</url>
  <name>Cloudera Repository</name>
</repository>
```

The repository has the followings files:
[image]

So in the pom I have the repository and the following dependency to reference the shaded artifact (cloudera-manager-api-5.8.1-shaded.jar):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.cloudera.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudera-manager-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.1</version>
    <classifier>shaded</classifier>
</dependency>
```

In the .m2 directory, Maven downloads the correct library, but there is an error at runtime, related to the shaded library.

If I remove the classifier tag and I change the version in the pom and in the .m2 directory(see below), it works.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.cloudera.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudera-manager-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.1-shaded</version>
</dependency>
```

.m2 directory:

```
-com
 -cloudera
  -api
   -cloudera-manager-api
    -5.8.1-shaded
      -(the library) cloudera-manager-api-5.6.1-shaded.jar
```

Do you know the reasons of this behaviour and how can use the shaded artifact without problems and without the last manual changes?

Comment: If the given output of the repository assumed that the second one (dependency without classifier) is correct as you already figured out..

Comment: The second one is the correct one because it works. But I would like to understand why do I have to change manually the pom and the .m2 directory?

Comment: There are two things. First the run time which means it could be cause by what's inside the shaded artifact (missing/changes etc.) second the not shaded only contains the dependency of it's own without supplemental aritfacts. And no you don't have to change the pom in .m2 cause that's a bad idea cause this is maintained by cloudera. Furthermore I have my doubts that the second one is correct cause I assume you have more dependencies in your pom...I assume the needed ones are already got as transitive deps..test is to clean up .m2/repositoy and rebuilt...and see if it works...

Comment: I have tried to clean everything and rebuilt without success...